# How to decode JSON data and show list using PHP

Tags: php, json

I have some JSON data as follows:

```
{
    "TABLE": [{
        "ROW": [{
            "COL": [{
                "DATA": "Buff momo"
            }, {
                "DATA": "60.00"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1;#"
            }, {
                "DATA": "0"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1"
            }, {
                "DATA": "118"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1;#{5D73B50D-2FFC-4D16-881E-D49328447AAB}"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1;#0"
            }, {
                "DATA": "2010-06-21 15:43:53"
            }, {
                "DATA": "Miscellaneous"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/1_.000"
            }]
        }, {
            "COL": [{
                "DATA": "Chicken drumstick"
            }, {
                "DATA": "100.00"
            }, {
                "DATA": "3;#"
            }, {
                "DATA": "0"
            }, {
                "DATA": "1"
            }, {
                "DATA": "3"
            }, {
                "DATA": "40"
            }, {
                "DATA": "3;#{A1E0F087-57D3-4039-991B-E08B1CB3892A}"
            }, {
                "DATA": "3;#0"
            }, {
                "DATA": "2010-06-21 15:44:14"
            }, {
                "DATA": "Chinese"
            }, {
                "DATA": "3;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/3_.000"
            }]
        }
        }]
    }]
}]
}
""
```

I tried to decode it as follows:

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
$json_string = utf8_encode(file_get_contents("filename"));
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string, true);
foreach ($parsed_json as $key => $value) {
}
```

but to no avail. I am gettig errors as Invalid argument supplied for foreach().
Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: ...aaaaand `$parsed_json` is magically springing up from where...?

Comment: @deceze sorry forgot to paste the line.have put it.

Comment: This has got to be the ugliest JSON i've seen in ages; whoever is returning this to you should be ashamed of it.  It seems clueless about the purpose of object keys.  What's with all the objects with the single key `"DATA"`?  Even if that were different for each row, it doesn't make sense that they're all separate rather than in one row object...

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is invalid. There are some brackets which do not belong there. The right JSON is

```
{ "TABLE":[{ "ROW":[ { "COL":[ {"DATA":"Buff momo"},{"DATA":"60.00"},{"DATA":"1;#"},{"DATA":"0"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"118"},{"DATA":"1;#{5D73B50D-2FFC-4D16-881E-D49328447AAB}"},{"DATA":"1;#0"},{"DATA":"2010-06-21 15:43:53"},{"DATA":"Miscellaneous"},{"DATA":"1;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/1_.000"}]}, { "COL":[ {"DATA":"Chicken drumstick"},{"DATA":"100.00"},{"DATA":"3;#"},{"DATA":"0"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"3"},{"DATA":"40"},{"DATA":"3;#{A1E0F087-57D3-4039-991B-E08B1CB3892A}"},{"DATA":"3;#0"},{"DATA":"2010-06-21 15:44:14"},{"DATA":"Chinese"},{"DATA":"3;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/3_.000"}]}]} ]}
```

you can test your JSON at http://json.parser.online.fr/

Comment: I have got data as you have said using json decode but I can't get  individual data.How am I to get it. Any suggesstions.

Comment: what do you mean by individual data? Give me an example. Try to show the whole content of the variable using `var_dump()`, this will give you an idea what is inside and how to access it.

Comment: I want to show data in each COL as a list but don't know how to process? Can you give me any suggesstions.

Comment: use eg $rows=$jsonobject["TABLE"][0]["ROW"]; to get a array with to entries, one for each row. As I said, using `var_dump()` will give you an idea of the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Use `json_decode` function for decoding json

*Updated : Example to show each COL as a list

```
<?php
$json_string = '{ "TABLE":[{ "ROW":[ { "COL":[ {"DATA":"Buff momo"},{"DATA":"60.00"},{"DATA":"1;#"},{"DATA":"0"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"118"},{"DATA":"1;#{5D73B50D-2FFC-4D16-881E-D49328447AAB}"},{"DATA":"1;#0"},{"DATA":"2010-06-21 15:43:53"},{"DATA":"Miscellaneous"},{"DATA":"1;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/1_.000"}]}, { "COL":[ {"DATA":"Chicken drumstick"},{"DATA":"100.00"},{"DATA":"3;#"},{"DATA":"0"},{"DATA":"1"},{"DATA":"3"},{"DATA":"40"},{"DATA":"3;#{A1E0F087-57D3-4039-991B-E08B1CB3892A}"},{"DATA":"3;#0"},{"DATA":"2010-06-21 15:44:14"},{"DATA":"Chinese"},{"DATA":"3;#Home/Lists/Canteen Menu/3_.000"}]}]} ]}';
$parsed_json = json_decode($json_string);
foreach ($parsed_json->TABLE[0]->ROW as $key => $value) {
    echo 'SELECT ' . $key . ': <select name="select' . $key . '">';
    foreach ($value->COL as $col) {
        echo '<option value="' . $col->DATA . '">' . $col->DATA . '</option>';
    }
    echo '</select>';
}
?>
```